# User input to run a function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, input, filter

I want to design a program in python in a way that it takes input from the user for a column value & calls the function which filters a dataframe based on the user input.

For example say user inputs "val1" the program should be able to call the function (already written) to do the following:

```
df_val1=df.loc[df["values"]=="val1"]
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: you can use `input()`

Comment: Do you want to stay within the console? Then use `input()` - otherwise, look into tkinter (messageboxes maybe?)